# in Angular 6.1.8 : I suddenly got this error : Cannot find module './populate-components'

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm working on a Angular 6.1.8 project with cli 6.2.2 and I suddenly got this error when trying to 'serve' or 'build' with the ng command:

```
Cannot find module './populate-components'
Error: Cannot find module './populate-components'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-2\properties\merge-into-shorthands.js:3:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\....\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-2\properties\optimize.js:1:89)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
```

I say suddenly because I really had the impression to change nothing...
I really even don't know where to look, I'm stuck... (not so confident in web development :-/)

If you  have any clue, thx !

Comment: Try running `npm install` again and see if populate-components gets installed.

Comment: Are you sure you've added the component to your app.module.ts file? 'populate-components' should be listed in your declarations array.. If it's a module (as the error states) it should be in your imports array.

Comment: I would say that you've made somewhere in imports a typo by accident and now you have this error

Comment: I think you missed to inject populate-component into @NgModule can you check it once

Comment: Thanks everyone for your kind comments!! Finally I've found a way to fix the situation... Don't understand how it gets corrupted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I've found the solution... 
The populate-modules was referenced only in the "clean-css" node module.
So I've deleted the folder of this module and runned 'npm install' again.
Now it works....

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a lost dependency.
Make sure that you have your dependency properly registered in your `package.json`

`npm install populate-components --save`

Then check that your component is declared in your `app.module.ts`

`import { PopulateComponents } from './populate-components';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [(...) PopulateComponents],`